# Making a HTML table fixed width based on its content

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make an HTML table. Let's say that it has 3 columns. I would like the first column's width to be fixed, and the other two columns expand/contract based on the available space and proportions between them.

That can all done simply enough by setting a fixed-size width for the first column, and using percentages for the other two. But I want something harder.

I want the browser to figure out the width itself.

I want it to get the ideal width of the column and then make that the column's fixed width. Rather than me having to eyeball text and find a width, the browser can just get the text's natural width and set that to be the column width.

This is something that is done fairly commonly in GUI layout grids, where you can have certain columns be of fixed size. The size is automatically determined by the size of the column's contents. The space left over after laying out the fixed size columns goes to the non-fixed sized ones.

Is there some way to do that in HTML/CSS?

Note that JavaScript is not an option here (it's in a wiki and I'd rather not introduce JavaScript there).

Comment: For what it's worth, there are a handful of CSS updates since 2013 that all solve this problem, though I am guessing you don't still have the need. CSS multi-column layout, CSS flexible box layout, and CSS grid layout all offer different solutions that could implement this.

Answer (score -1):

This is not too difficult, but it doesn't have an exact sizing for the content unless you define it. With this `table` you'll see the middle column as the widest:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:none;">
    <tr>
        <td width="150" valign="top">This is a fixed width column, it's only 50 pixels wide</td>
        <td valign="top">This is a variable width column that has a lot of content</td>
        <td valign="top">This is also a variable width column as well</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

If you swap the content of the middle and last cells you'll see that the content width shift with the content.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:none;">
    <tr>
        <td width="150" valign="top">This is a fixed width column, it's only 50 pixels wide</td>
        <td valign="top">This is also a variable width column as well</td>
        <td valign="top">This is a variable width column that has a lot of content</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Now, you can also play off this by nesting a table in a cell with a fixed width. In the next example, it is the center column. This way you can let last column's width grow and just take up the space.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:none;">
    <tr>
        <td width="150" valign="top">This is a fixed width column, it's only 50 pixels wide</td>
        <td valign="top">
            <table width="130" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:none;">
                <tr>
                    <td>This is a fixed width table's content inside of a nested table</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">This is a variable width column that has a lot of content and should push the boundaries</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

With that, you have a few strategies for how to handle fluid content within a table.

**** -- UPDATE -- **

Perhaps I read that wrong, sorry.

Tables operate to always get the column width from the widest cell. If you have several rows with content of varying width the columns will all inherit the widest cell width within the column. So, to make a table's column fixed width you either need to have content that is a fixed width or wrap the content in an element that is a fixed width.

gMail, Google Reader, and a lot of online email clients use a similar approach to have a fixed width nav on the left and let the rendering area grow with the user's browser.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:none;">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <table width="50" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:none;">
                <tr>
                    <td>This is a fixed width column, it's only 50 pixels wide</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <table width="130" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:none;">
                <tr>
                    <td>This is a fixed width table's content inside of a nested table</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">This is a variable width column that has a lot of content and should push the boundaries</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

They normally do this in CSS but with this approach you do not define the width of the table cells. They will just inherit their width from the content. The third column, which has no fixed width on its content, will grow with the user's web browser width and be fluid.

Comment: That's very interesting. But I don't see the part where you're making a column fixed-width without giving it a *specific* fixed-width size. Because your fixed-width column is given a width.

Comment: On your edit: Again, you've missed the point. I want the width of a column defined by the width of its *content*, and be *fixed* at the native content width. That way, if the user uses different font settings or whatever, the layout still works and it doesn't break lines. *I don't want to type a numeric width*.